# Multiple Linux OS: Wireless works at home & on cellphone hotspot, sometimes won't connect away

Tags: wifi, network-interface

Can't find the explanation for this, but I'm having issue with WiFi connections on my laptop. My primary OS is Manjaro 19.0.2. But I have the same issue with Kubuntu and Linux Mint (installed for testing purposes).

Laptop can't connect to some WiFi networks, without any explanation. Can connect to some networks, but it gets disconnected every several minutes (10-15 minutes interval, after several disconnects it won't connect again). But it works without any problem on other networks.

Sometimes restarting network-manager helps, but sometimes doesn't.

For example, if I enable hotspot on my smartphone - it always works. Same with WiFi at home. But, let's say, WiFi in the coffee shop - it will be 50/50 chance. WiFi itself is not a problem, because it works with my smartphone or iPad. The issue is with the laptop.

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: Please advise the security used by each WiFi network involved, and whether its channel is in 2.4 GHz or a 5GHz bands. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: @K7AAY I wasn't sure what facts can I provide, I didn't see any pattern. But I think I finally found the solution - `fwupdmgr update`. So far 5 hours uptime and everything seems to be working. I'll do more test and close the question if the issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried many different things - nothing helped. Until I tried to update the firmware: `fwupdmgr update` (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fwupd#Usage). It solved my problem.